# How to check if dates overlap on different lines in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, date

I have a database with electricity meter readings. Sometimes people get a new meter and then their original meter gets an end date and the new meter gets a start date and the end date remains NULL. This can happen multiple times in a year and I want to know if there are no gaps in measurement. In other words, I need to figure out if end date 1 is the same as start date 2 and so on.

Sample data:

```
cust_id meter_id     start_date         end_date
--------------------------------------------------
   a       1         2017-01-01         2017-05-02
   a       2         2017-05-02         Null
   b       3         2017-01-01         2017-06-01
   b       4         2017-06-05         Null
```

This is what the data looks like and the result I am looking for is that for customer a the end date of meter 1 is equal to the start date of meter 2. For customer b however, there are 4 days between the end date of meter 3 and the start date of meter 4. That is something I want to flag.

I found customers for whom this can happen up to 8 times in the period I am researching. I tried something with nested queries and very complex cases but even I lost my way around it, so I was wondering if someone here has an idea of how to get to the answer a little smarter.

Comment: First your inner select should have `row_number partition by cust_id` then join table on itself by `cust_id` and a.row_number - 1 = b.row_number (to get change by change) and having `DateDiff(days, a.end_date, b.Start_date) > 1`

Answer (score 5):

You can get the offending rows using `lag()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lag(end_date) over (partition by cust_id, meter_id order by start_date) as prev_end_date,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id, meter_id order by start_date) as seqnum
      from readings r
     ) r
where prev_end_date <> start_date or prev_end_date is null and seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: ^^^  Nice code, upvoted.  I really should update my article to use LEAD and LAG.

Comment: This is indeed a very elegant solution! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Guessing there is now a better way to pull this off using LEAD and LAG, but I wrote an article in SQL 2008R2 called [T-SQL: Identify bad dates in a time series](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12236/T-SQL-Identify-bad-dates-in-a-time-series.html) where you can modify the big cte in the middle of the article to handle your definition of a bad date.

Good luck.  There's too much detail in the article to post in a single SO question, otherwise I'd do that here.